# TeamCity: How to get a list of last builds for each build configuration that are currently not running?

Tags: api, rest, teamcity

I am using TeamCity 7.1. I want to get a list including the last build of each build configuration (build type) that is currently not running. I found this question: [TeamCity - How do you get a list of the last finished build of each project through rest api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089462/teamcity-how-do-you-get-a-list-of-the-last-finished-build-of-each-project-thro) but the REST URI in the answer did not work for me.

```
<teamcity-server>/httpAuth/app/rest/builds?locator=sinceBuild:(status:failure)
```

seems to work and gives me all builds that succeeded after failing before.

But the opposite

```
<teamcity-server>/httpAuth/app/rest/builds?locator=sinceBuild:(status:success)
```

does not return any builds.

I know that I can get all build types, iterate though them and get the most recent finished build using

```
<teamcity-server>/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/id:<build-type-id>/builds/running:false?count=1&start=0
```

("count=1&start=0" may not be necessary)
but I am not really sure that what I get is really the latest build. Also this requires many REST calls for all build types. A neat solution would use only one REST call.

Any ideas?

Comment: I tried, both `<teamcity-server>/httpAuth/app/rest/builds?locator=sinceBuild:(status:failure)` and `<teamcity-server>/httpAuth/app/rest/builds?locator=sinceBuild:(status:success)` and those are working. The second might not be working for you since you may not be having any builds after the last successful build. Then it will return 0 count. By and large at a time either of them will give you a 0 count because your last build will either be a SUCCESS or a FAILURE.

Answer (score 5):

As per the [TeamCity REST API documentation from JetBrains](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin), the builds can be located either of the following ways:

```
<teamcity-server>/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/id:<build-type-id>/builds/running:false,status:success
```

OR

```
<teamcity-server>/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/running:false,status:success
```

This is must to have the buildType is being suffixed by a `<buildTypeLocator>` as per the current REST API if you are trying to query something under the buildType and `<buildTypeLocator> can be id:<btXXX_internal_buildConfiguration_id> or name:<Build_Configuration_name>` (Quote from documentation). So it is must that you need to specify build id or build name.

But, the ideal way as you expected will be something like:

```
<teamcity-server>/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/builds/running:false,status:success
```

Probably, you can raise this up in [TeamCity Support](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/community/teamcity) I suppose.

Comment: This will not get the last finished build, but *all* builds.